# Cannot Match CryptoJS HMAC Generated Signature with Java HMAC Signature

Tags: javascript, java, scala

I am trying to convert some Javascript code that uses the CryptoJS library to compute the HMAC signature but I cannot get the same output. I am not sure if I am being stupid here and whether it's possible or not to get the same value with different libraries or if I am making a mistake somewhere.

Here is the Javascript code

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

api_key = "my-key";
api_secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("my-secret");
api_nonce = 1;
api_endpoint = "/endpoint";
api_post = "nonce=" + api_nonce;


api_sha256 = CryptoJS.SHA256(api_nonce + api_post);

api_sign = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA512, api_secret);
api_sign.update(api_endpoint, api_secret);
api_sign.update(api_sha256, api_secret);

console.log(api_sign.finalize().toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
```

This produces `iySXN0IazUqD1Y+v+tHFpNVRG29Mlb545H3jLZ9FI6xmpF1giZFgoyWlXgWoUL3hJYtlTSzrdOjbg6hEL/7bxA==`

The Scala code I have which uses the Java crypto libraries is as follows:

```scala
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.util.Base64
import javax.crypto.Mac
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec


val api_key = "my-key"
val api_secret =  "my-secret"
val api_nonce    = "1"
val api_endpoint = "/endpoint"
val api_post     = s"nonce=$api_nonce"

val md           = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
val api_sha256   = md.digest((api_nonce + api_post).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

val byteKey    = api_secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
val sha512Hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512")
val keySpec    = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, "HmacSHA512")
sha512Hmac.init(keySpec)

sha512Hmac.update(api_endpoint.getBytes)
sha512Hmac.update(api_sha256)

val macData = sha512Hmac.doFinal()

val result = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(macData)

result
```

This produces `rWM90XbSRMysBoyQtNx52oFyDxRMGAtygz1zb9UoGQCEHtcL5b22wx7KHC4XckXHPmsBDrZ6ZamHvVurhC6W6A==`